# How to extract words from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, substring, extract

I've imported a file and turned it into a String called readFile. The file contains two lines:

```
qwertyuiop00%
qwertyuiop
```

I have already extracted the "00" from the string using: 
    String number = readFile.substring(11, 13);

I now want to extract the "ert" and the "uio" in "qwertyuiop"
When I try to use the same method as the first, like so:

```
String e = readFile.substring(16, 19);
String u = readFile.substring(20, 23);
```

and try to use:

```
System.out.println(e + "and" + u);
```

It says string index out of range.

How do I go about this?
Is it because the next two words I want to extract from the string are on the second line?
If so, how do I extract only the second line?
I want to keep it basic, thanks.

UPDATE:
it turns out only the first line of the file is being read, does anyone know how to make it so it reads both lines?

Comment: `It won't work.` What actually happening ?

Comment: why dont you use regexp for substring? Or why you need this? Maybe if you tell us the problem what you want to solve we can give you a simply solution.

Comment: Your second line is shorter, 10 characters you try to substring at more. You may use regexps .

Comment: Why not put each line into it's own string?  Why are you combining the entire file's contents into one string?

Comment: using string spliiter should work

Answer (score 0):

If you count the total number of characters for each string, they are more than the indexes your entering.

qwertyuiop00% is 13 characters. Call `.length()` method on the string to verify the length is the one you expect.

I would debug with adding the following before:

```
System.out.println(readFile);
System.out.println(readFile.length());
```

**Note:**

`qwertyuiop00% qwertyuiop` is 24 characters since space counts as a character. Unless ofcourse you don't have the space in which it's 23 characters and your indexes are 0 to 22

**Note2:**

I asked for the parser code since I suspect your using the usual code which is something like:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

You need to concatenate those lines into one String (though it's not the best approach).

see: [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

Comment: qwertyuiop00%
qwertyuiop  all together is 23 characters?

Comment: Can you give us the parsing code? Also have you printed out that this is actually the value within the variable?

Comment: I think he needs to take the lenght to avoid mistake and also he can test if substring exists : if(string.contains("uio"))

Comment: I think she wants the characters in those positions, not strictly 'ert' or 'uio'

Comment: There's also the issue if the file is using linux or windows file endings. And without the parser/file we don't know A) if it works correctly and B)if line ending is 2 characters or 1

Comment: The file is definitely the value within the variable, as I have already used the variable to extract the "00" on the first line. I'm sorry but I don't know what a parsing code is...

Comment: @hheather qwertyuiop00% qwertyuiop is 24 characters since space counts as a character. Unless ofcourse you don't have the space in which it's 23 characters and your indexes are 0 to 22

Comment: I just asked it for the length of the file and it's only returning the length of the first line, not the length of the first and second combined?

Comment: I think your using `readline()` in your parser, which means your not reading both lines into 1 string.

Answer (score 0):

First split your string into lines, you could do this using

```
String[] lines = readFile.split("[\r\n]+");
```

You may want to read the content directly into a `List<String>` using [Files.#readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) instead.

second, do not use hard coded indexes, use [String#indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) to find them out. If a substring does not occur in your original string, then the method retunrs `-1`, always check for that value and call `substring` only when the return value is not `-1` (0 or greater).

```
if(lines.length > 1) {
    int startIndex = lines[1].indexOf("ert");
    if(startIndex != -1) {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

Btw, there is no point in extracting already known substring from a string

```
System.out.println(e + "and" + u);
```

is equivalent to

```
System.out.println("ertanduio");
```

Knowing the start and end position of a fixed substring makes only sence if you want to do something with rest of original string, for example removing the substrings.

Comment: readAllLines or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file :)

Answer (score 0):

You may give this a try:-

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(new FileReader(new File(The file path for readFile.txt)));
String st="";
while(sc.hasNext()){
st=sc.next();
}
System.out.println(st.substring(2,5)+" "+"and"+" "+st.substring(6,9));
```

Check out if it works.